# How can I make Compiz and Metacity co-exist happily? I only have one or the other

Tags: compiz, metacity

While experimenting with sending virtual keystrokes, things got seriously hung up!  I powered off, When the system restarted all window decoration was missing, and all fancy compiz graphics was missing.

I ran `metacity --replace`. That brought back the window decoration, but still no **compiz**. I ran `compiz --replace`, that brought back compiz functionality, but this time, no **window decoration**.

How can I get Compiz and Metacity back together again?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Compiz and Metacity are both window managers. You cannot use two different window managers at the same time. However, windows' decoration is done by a window decorator, not a window manager. You can use, e.g., either `gtk-window-decorator` (which can match your previous MetaCity themes), or Beryl's own `emerald` window decorator, which was made to work with Compiz, and has lots of nice themes.

Whatever you choose, be sure to check the settings for Compiz's Window Decorator plugin. (Run CompizConfig Settings Manager or `ccsm` and enable that plugin, and choose either `gtk-window-decorator` or `emerald` for the command; perhaps adding `--replace` if it helps.)

Comment: I'm still tying to figure out what's going on here... In Compiz,"Window Decoration" I have `/usr/bin/compiz-decorator --replace`(the default doesn't have the "--replace")... I now get the window decoraton.. but I haven't actuall changed anything (that I know of), and now my **Panel** has gone missing! .... I'll reboot ....

Comment: I'm finally back from *many* reboots.. Some of the *unusual* behaviour comes from issueing commands in this form `metacity --replace`/` compiz --replace`. This causes semi-waiting states in the terminal which, for metacity, gives **no** decoration, until I repeat "metacity --replace" consecutively... However it works **every time** with `(metacity --replace&)`/`(compiz --replace&)`. Also, issuing the `no-bracket, no-&` form via Alt-F2 works too..  And I now understand a lot better, how these items fit into the scheme of things.. eg: `(emerald --replace&)` when Compiz is the manager :) Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Compiz and Metacity are both [compositing window managers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compositing_window_manager). That can't coexist--you can only have one or the other.

Really your problem is that you're missing window decorations with compiz. Can you post the output of `compiz --replace`? I don't know enough to help you here, but maybe someone else does. Also explain exactly what you were doing when the decorations disappeared.

Comment: Aha!.. Does that mean that Compiz is **more** than just a *"window manager"*, and that when Metacity is the mangager, the fancy Compiz graphics actually have nothing to do with Compiz's **"window management"** functions? ..... Re the crash: I ran a command similar to this `echo -n "KeyStrPress a KeyStrRelease a" | xmacroplay -d 1 :0.0 `  but with Control and Alt keys, and it **seemed** to leave them in a pressed state.. Attempts to close the terminal via the mouse locked things up &>/dev/null

Answer (score 2):

I face the problem often. Try installing the compiz fusion icon -package name 'fusion-icon'. Once installed it will show up in your system tray. Trying playing around with the settings. Indirect rendering tends to solve this problem sometimes.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue when I upgraded the driver for my graphics card, I recommend you install Ubuntu Tweak - it will easily enable you to configure compiz and advanced window effects without the need for a terminal.